# Better way to call a stored procedure using Entity Framework and return restfully from WCF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I want to create a WCF service that calls a stored procedure in SQL Server using the Entity Framework and returns the result set to a browser.

I imported the stored procedure using the function import in EF and I built a complex type.

It seems that a complex type from the EF cannot be serialized and returned restfully. The only way I have made this work is to create a concrete class and build it from the complex type returned from EF. This works but it means if I have 30 stored procedures I would need to create 30 concrete classes which is somewhat of a pain.

Is there a better way to do this?

WCF contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract,WebGet,XmlSerializerFormat]
    List<People> usp_GetPeople();    
}
```

Concrete class would need to be created for every procedure:

```
public class People
{
    public int person_id;
    public string last_name;
    public string first_name;
    public string street_addr;
    public string state_code;
    public string postal_code;

    public People(int person_id, string last_name, string first_name, string street_addr, string state_code, string postal_code)
    {
        this.person_id = person_id;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.street_addr = street_addr;
        this.state_code = state_code;
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
    }

    public People() { }
}
```

WCF service:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
/// <summary>
/// Call stored proc and return resultset.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>List of resultset as concrete class People.</returns>
public List<People> usp_GetPeople()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new demoEntities())
        {
            var res = db.usp_GetPeople();

            List<People> lst = new List<People>();

            foreach (usp_GetPeople_Result r in res)
            {
                People p = new People(r.person_id, r.last_name, r.first_name, r.street_addr, r.state_code, r.postal_code);
                lst.Add(p);
            }

            return lst;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Utility.Log("Error in usp_GetPeople. " + e.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you are trying to return the type created by EF?

Comment: Could it be that your object (People) isn't decorated with the data attributes? (DataContract / DataMember) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WCF1.usp_GetPeople_Result>' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<WCF1.usp_GetPeople_Result>' 
I went back and tried again.  Basically it looks like I just need to return a List<Person> instead of a ObjectResult<Person>.  It works that way.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is to return a List of the EF complex type.

```
 public List<usp_GetPeople_Result> usp_GetPeople2()
    {
        using (var db = new demoEntities())
        {
            return db.usp_GetPeople().ToList();
        }
    }
```

This will not work:

```
 public ObjectResult<usp_GetPeople_Result> usp_GetPeople3()
    {
        using (var db = new demoEntities())
        {
            return db.usp_GetPeople();
        }
    }
```